# AWS Cloudwatch (EventBridge) Event Rule for AWS Batch with Environment Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I have created a Cloudwatch Event (EventBridge) Rule that triggers an AWS Batch Job and I want to specify an environment variable and parameters. I'm trying to do so with the following Configured Input (Constant [JSON text]), but when the job is submitted, then environment variables I'm trying to setup in the job with are not included and the parameters are the defaults.  The parameters are working as expected.

```
{
    "ContainerProperties": {
        "Environment": [
            {
                "Name": "MY_ENV_VAR",
                "Value": "MyVal"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Parameters": {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As I was typing out the question, I actually thought to look at the Submit Job API to see what I was doing wrong (I was referencing the CFTs for the Job Definition as my thought process above).  For others it may help, I found that I needed to use `ContainerOverrides` rather than `ContainerProperties` to have it work properly.

```
{
    "ContainerOverrides": {
        "Environment": [
            {
                "Name": "MY_ENV_VAR",
                "Value": "NorthAmerica"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Parameters": {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting to note that the capitalisation of `Environment`, `Name` and `Value` were the key to me getting this to run, which is at odds with other parts of the [AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html#containerProperties)

Comment: i have the same issues, but still my python container not taking the environment variables. this is the json inside Constant [JSON text] -> {"ContainerOverrides" : {"Environment": [{"Name":"application", "Value" : "liberty"},{"Name" : "environment", "Value" : "dev" }] }}, can u figure out what am i missing here?

Comment: Like many other gotchas in AWS services, there is a note about the capitalization of the properties buried in the [docs for Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-cwe-target.html). The docs only describe how to use the input transformer, so you may have overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

The preceding solution DIDN'T work for me.  The correct answer can be found here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/batch-parameters-trigger-cloudwatch/

I was only able to pass parameters to the job like so:

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "customers": "tgc,localhost"
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to get environment variables to work and didn't try ContainerOverrides.